# Assign mouse click handler to line in d3 with snapping behaviour

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, mouse

I have a d3 line that is only one pixel wide. I want to have a on-click
handler assigned to this line. However it is very hard to be exactly on top of the line when trying to select it. Is there some "selection corridor" feature that lets you specify a "distance to line" instead. I.e. the click event is fired if the mouse pointer is, say, in a distance of max 8pt away from a line and the mouse is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44250761/5768908) is a good solution and an interesting one.

However, I prefer the "traditional" solution, which is painting **another** line, transparent and thicker than the visible thin line, just to catch the click event. And the reason I prefer this "traditional" solution (the most frequent one among D3 coders) is UX: it's a good idea letting the user know that she/he can click the line.

Thus, the advantage of having a thicker, transparent line over the thin, visible line is that you can set the cursor to a hand...

```
.attr("cursor", "pointer")
```

... when the user hover over the transparent line.

Here is a simple demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = d3.range(30).map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: d * 10,
    y: Math.random() * 150
  }
});
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y
  });

var realLine = svg.append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "teal")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("d", lineGenerator(data));

var transparentLine = svg.append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "teal")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke-width", 12)
  .attr("opacity", 0)
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator(data));

transparentLine.on("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Of course, this "traditional" solution only makes sense if you have one or few lines on that chart. If you have dozens or hundreds of lines, it will be a complete mess.

Answer (score 1):

You can attack click event on svg/group element and check if the distance from the mouse position and the closest point on the path is less than some fixed value, e.g. 4. The distance can be calculated using the function from [Closest Point on Path example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8027637).

Click event:

```
var path = svg.append('path').datum(data).attr("d", line);
svg.on('click', function() {
  var m = d3.mouse(this),
    p = closestPoint(path.node(), m);

  if (p.distance < 4) {
    /* make action */
    console.log('click', p.distance)
  }
})
```

`closestPoint()` is taken from the example above.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/xny9bx4v/